# Andrpoid blend modes not working as expected

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

Pretty much all blend modes i tried are not working as expected. Below are a few of those. Keep in mind that dst=green, src=red.

**NO BLEND**
[image]

**DST, DST_IN (this result is ok for DST, but not for DST_IN)**
[image]

**SRC (bad result)**
[image]

My View:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

class MyView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
    val blendPaint = Paint()
    val simplePaint = Paint()
    init {
        blendPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)
        blendPaint.color = Color.argb(255,255,0,0)
        simplePaint.color = Color.argb(255,0,255,0)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas!!.drawRect(Rect(0, 0, 400, 400), simplePaint)
        canvas.drawRect(Rect(200, 200, 600, 600), blendPaint)
    }


    private fun mutableBitmap(resId: Int): Bitmap {
        val immutable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, resId)
        return immutable.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    }

}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <com.example.scrp01.com.example.scrp01.MyView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This a newly created project, no changes on AndroidManifest at all, running on API 26 Android 8.0, CPU x86. Android Studio version 3.3.2

You can see what would be the appropriate results here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode.html#SRC

Comment: try `Canvas#saveLayer` before any `Canvas#drawRect` calls

Comment: Tried that, did not work. Do I just need to use save? No restore?

Comment: I did read, why would I need to use save/restore when I'm not even doing operations on the canvas? Also saveLayer is completely optional according to the docs, and so is restoreToCount.

Comment: Of course you are doing operations on canvas: you are calling drawRect twice

Comment: I tried calling save() before first drawRect, then restore before the second drawRect. Nothing changed.

Comment: so you have to work with `drawBitmap` - i found working with primitive `draw*` methods very difficult too - i 'm still surprised they dont mention it in `Canvas` docs

Comment: [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.java) you have all the blend modes in one place